# How to develop cross platform app library

Tags: android, ios, react-native, cross-platform

We currently have the situation that we need to create an Android library (aar) and an iOS Framework. You know about the benefits, so we would like to have this done in a cross-platform manner. There is a strong React Native background in our company, but since there is no official solution to achieve this, we would be open for other suggestions as well. I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35283427/bundling-react-native-project-as-ios-framework-or-aar-android-library) that this can be done. However the mentioned solution has major drawbacks, such as the .framework size in iOS. Does anyone have a better approach for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can view [Kotlin/Native](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/native-overview.html) for crossplatform libraries.

> Kotlin/Native supports two-way interoperability with the Native world.
>   On the one hand, the compiler creates:
>
> - an executable for many platforms
> - a static library or dynamic library    with C headers for C/C++ projects
> - an Apple framework for Swift and    Objective-C projects
>
> On the other hand, Kotlin/Native supports interoperability to use
>   existing libraries directly from Kotlin/Native:
>
> - static or dynamic C Libraries
> - C, Swift, and Objective-C frameworks