# Unable to run Android App with .aar file generated from React Native App

Tags: android, react-native, aar

I am trying to publish an Android lib (.aar) which is created from React native code
by:

1. creating a bundle file from React native App
2. Use the bundle file in Existing Android App inside a module
3. Generate aar file from the module
4. use the aar file else where

Followed the reference post :
https://medium.com/@gauravasrivastava89/sdk-development-with-react-native-part-1-46580839eae9

The Library code as a module runs fine with or without metro server

It also runs fine with .aar file as dependency in other app when metro server is running.

But when Metro server is stopped, I am getting a blank page in the App with the following error in the console.

> E/ReactNativeJS: Invariant Violation: "MyReactNativeApp" has not been
> registered. This can happen if:
> * Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
> * A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called.

Any other dependency from node_module to be added in the library to enable it for offline usage ?

Comment: @ggsrivas any input on the above.

Comment: "MyReactNativeApp" is registered in the "index.android.bundle" file. Please verify that this file is added to your sdk's .aar file.
Can you also explain the use case when it's failing? Is it your Dev app where SDK java code is present and "index.android.bundle" is present as an asset? or is it the app, where .aar file is included as external SDK?

Comment: @ggsrivas, thanks for the response. I verified and the aar file includes bundle file as an asset. The app fails where the aar file is included as external SDK.

Comment: @ggsrivas, when the metro server is started , I am able to run the external app with aar file (created from React Native) but it doesn't work with out the metro server. Am I missing something ?

Comment: I re created the whole process again and it worked fine.May be due to some mismatch in the module it wasn't working.