# How to export React Native as .aar (for android) and .framework (for IOS)?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

im new for this journey but i had research about this, like for 3 days maybe or later, and found so many Blog but without any tutorial to achive this.

according to this [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35283427/bundling-react-native-project-as-ios-framework-or-aar-android-library) , it seems he/she finally can achive this AAR and .framework, but i still not understand how to generate that from react native.

can somebody tell me , where should i found this tutorial to make it ? im a bit frustated because i cannot solve this.
maybe any reference , step by step using an existing React Native Project then finnaly generate AAR and .framework, it will very very very usefull for me.

i hope someone can help me to solve this :(

Comment: I know a tutorial but in Turkish: https://medium.com/fiba-tech-lab/halihaz%C4%B1rdaki-bir-react-native-uygulamas%C4%B1n%C4%B1-k%C3%BCt%C3%BCphane-haline-getirip-github-packages-%C3%BCzerinden-b5229c068be9 Maybe helps.

Comment: @ridvanaltun thanks for sharing bro, i will try it. still confusing about this, i dont even know the keyword for this on Youtube, maybe i can follow someone tutorial in video instead because hard for me to learn from just a post

Comment: Actually, I don't know but try to search this: react-native as android lib

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve this by [Electrode Native](https://www.electrode.io/site/native.html)

With [Electrode Native](https://www.electrode.io/site/native.html), you can work on cross-platform components written in JavaScript using React Native, that can then be added to any iOS or Android mobile application. It outputs **.aar** file for android & **.framework** for iOS.

Comment: but, i already make my own application using react native cli, how to deal with it ?